# If $A$ is a $k \times k$ submatrix of $n \times n$ unitary matrix and $2k>n$. why that some singular value of $A$ is equal to $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is a $k \times k$ submatrix of $n \times n$ unitary matrix and $2k>n$. why does some singular value of $A$ is equal to $1$?

Comment: The claim from your question is not true. Denote by $E$ the $3\times3$ identity matrix, i.e. $E$ has entries $1$ on the diagonal and $0$ elsewhere. Put $U = iE,$ where $i^2 = -1.$ Then $U$ is unitary with sole eigenvalue $i.$ Let $A$ be the $2\times2$ upper left submatrix of $U.$ Then we have $n = 3$ and $k = 2,$ and thus $2k > n.$ But $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A,$ since $A$ also has the sole eigenvalue $i.$

Comment: @jflipp : singular value

Answer (score 3):

Let $Q\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times k}$, $n\geq k$, such that $Q^*Q=I$ and consider the partitioning
$$
Q=\left(\begin{array}{c}Q_1\\Q_2\end{array}\right)\begin{array}{l}\}\;k\\\}\;n-k\end{array}.
$$
Since $Q$ has orthonormal columns, for any $x\in\mathbb{C}^k$ such that $\|x\|_2=1$,
$$
1=\|x\|_2^2=\|Qx\|_2^2=\|Q_1x\|_2^2+\|Q_2x\|_2^2.
$$
Hence
$$\tag{1}
\sigma_{\max}(Q_1)=\max_{\|y\|_2=1}\|Q_1y\|_2=\left(1-\min_{\|y\|_2=1}\|Q_2y\|_2^2\right)^{1/2}.
$$
So if $Q_2$ has a nontrivial nullspace, the minimum on the right-hand side is zero and hence the maximal singular value of $Q_1$ is equal to 1. A sufficient condition for this is that $Q_2$ has more columns than rows, that is, $k>n-k$, or, $2k>n$. By a more careful use of the variational characterization of singular values instead of (1), one can show that the multiplicity of this singular value is given by the dimension of the nullspace of $Q_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Q\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times k}$, $n\geq k$, such that $Q^*Q=I$ and consider the partitioning

$$
Q=\begin{bmatrix}
Q_1  \\
Q_2      
\end{bmatrix}\begin{matrix}
\}&k\\
\}&n-k\\
\end{matrix}
$$
Since $Q$ has orthonormal columns,  we see that
$$
I_k=Q^*Q=Q_1^*Q_1+Q_2^*Q_2.
$$
Let the SVD of $Q_1$ be
$$
Q_1=V\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{smallmatrix}
\sigma_1                     &                          &            &            \\
                               &\sigma_2                &            &            \\
                               &                          &\ddots      &            \\
                               &                          &            &\sigma_k  \\
\end{smallmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}W^*,
$$

so we have
$$
Q_2^*Q_2= I_k-Q_1^*Q_1=W\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{smallmatrix}
1-\sigma_1^2                     &                          &            &            \\
                               &1-\sigma_2^2                &            &            \\
                               &                          &\ddots      &            \\
                               &                          &            &1-\sigma_k^2  \\
\end{smallmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}W^*.
$$

Notice that $\mathrm{rank}(Q_2)=\mathrm{rank}(Q_2^*Q_2)$. Thus,
$$\mathrm{rank}(Q_2)=\mathrm{rank}(\mathrm{diag}[1-\sigma_1^2 ,1-\sigma_2^2 ,\ldots, 1-\sigma_k^2])=k-m$$
i.e.
$$ m=k-\mathrm{rank}(Q_2)$$
where $m$ is  the number of singular values $\sigma_i=1$. If $k>n-k$, then
this equality says that
$$m=k-\mathrm{rank}(Q_2)\geq k-(n-k)=2k-n$$